# yum no longer able to detect/access repository

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

Yum was working fine until I tried to install google chrome and used the `--add-repo` command with which I added chrome's repository.

Ever since then, whenever I do a `sudo yum install`, yum only searched on chrome's repository.

So I removed the repo file of chrome. But even after restarting the system, yum is not accessing any repository.

A `sudo yum search gtk+` turned up results for gtk+, but trying to install it with `sudo yum install gtk2.x86_64` didn't work. It gave the output:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Nothing to do
```

How can I fix this? I'm using Fedora 20, 64 bit version.

`ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d` shows me the following output:

> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  183 Jan 26 19:03 adobe-linux-x86_64.repo
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Feb  2 09:34 fedora.repo
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Feb  2 09:34 fedora-updates.repo
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Feb  2 09:34 fedora-updates-testing.repo
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   75 Jan 26 11:52 jenkins.repo
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   76 Jan 26 11:51 jenkins.repo.rpmnew
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1241 Mar 14  2013 rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1172 Jan 26 19:04 rpmfusion-free.repo
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1170 Jan 26 19:03 rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1230 Jun 29  2013 rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo

Comment: What does `ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d` show you?

Comment: If you have Fedora 20, you must have Yum Extender (or similar). You can easly add and substract repos.

Comment: @samiam: I've edited the question to show you the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure who told you to use the `--add-repo` switch but this is almost never the "right" way to go about adding new repositories. Rather you should either use a `.rpm`  file for the repository that you're attempting to install, and use `rpm -ivh somerepo.rpm` to install that repositories `.repo` file into the directory `/etc/yum.repo.d/` and the RPM keys visible when you run the command `rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*`.

```
$ rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*
gpg-pubkey-e06f8c93-51760257
gpg-pubkey-98ab5139-4bf2d0b0
gpg-pubkey-7fac5991-4615767f
gpg-pubkey-fb4b18e6-50b96bfd
...
```

You can also make a repository file manually for Chrome using one of these 2 samples that are described in this ifthenelse blog post titled: [Enable Google YUM repository](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-google-chrome-with-yum-on-fedora-red-hat-rhel/).

**32-bit**

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome - 32-bit
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/i386
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

**64-bit**

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome - 64-bit
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

This would've saved you the pain you're in now. But back to resolving that now.

#### Diagnosing with RPM

You can use RPM to determine which RPMs have been impacted, I'd focus on RPMs that are related to installing `.repo` files to start, as well as packages related to `yum` itself, since I suspect your `/etc/yum.conf` file or the lower level `.repo` files are at fault here.

You can check the consistency of files comparing their checksum that's maintained in the RPM database like so:

```
$ rpm -qfVv /etc/yum.conf /etc/yum.repo.d/*
.........  c /etc/logrotate.d/yum
.........    /etc/yum
.........  c /etc/yum.conf
.........    /etc/yum.repos.d
.........    /etc/yum/fssnap.d
.........    /etc/yum/pluginconf.d
.........    /etc/yum/protected.d
.........    /etc/yum/vars
.........  c /etc/yum/version-groups.conf
.........    /usr/bin/yum
...
```

This output shows whether any files associated to the RPM that `/etc/yum.conf` has been modified or is corrupt. If a file had been modified the output would look like this:

```
$ touch /etc/yum.conf
$ rpm -qfVv /etc/yum.conf
.........  c /etc/logrotate.d/yum
.........    /etc/yum
.......T.  c /etc/yum.conf
...
```

Notice the `T` in the column of dots to the left. This tells us that the time on the file differs. See the man page for `rpm` for more on the `-V` or `--verify` switch.

> Each of the 9 characters denotes the result of a comparison of attribute(s) of  the  file to the value of those attribute(s) recorded in the database.  A single 
>   "." (period) means the test passed, while a single "?" (question mark) indicates 
>   the test could not be performed (e.g. file permissions  prevent  reading). 
>   Otherwise,  the (mnemonically emBoldened) character denotes failure of the corresponding `--verify` test:
>
> ```
>    S file Size differs
>    M Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)
>    5 digest (formerly MD5 sum) differs
>    D Device major/minor number mismatch
>    L readLink(2) path mismatch
>    U User ownership differs
>    G Group ownership differs
>    T mTime differs
>    P caPabilities differ
> ```

You'll likely need to re-download the offending RPM and re-install it using `rpm`.

#### Are my repositories disabled?

You can use this command to confirm that the adding of the Chrome YUM repository didn't accidentally delete the other YUM repositories. This command will do it:

```
$ yum repolist all
```

**screenshot of output**

[image: ss of yum]

Notice the column to the right. Any repos that are disabled are red, any that are enabled are green. Check to make sure that all the repos are enabled (green).

If they aren't then you can either go through the `.repo` files and changed the offending ones to "ENABLED=1" or use `yum-config-manager` to re-enable them.

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable <repo name>
```

#### I'm stuck...my .repo files are "hosed"???

If you find that your `.repo` files are in a bad way. Perhaps they're zero length files now, then your yum setup is essentially pretty screwed up. But all is not lost. You can get things back into shape using `rpm` and `yum`.

1. Can't I just re-install RPMs?

   Yes you can, but which to install? If you don't know which ones to install you can deduce the versions like so, using your existing RPM database. I'm on F19 so these are the corresponding packages for the `fedora*.repo` files.

   ```
   $ rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora* | sort -u
   fedora-release-19-6.noarch
   ```

   So you're looking for an `.rpm`  file named `fedora-release-20*.noarch`. Here's that file from the install media for F20:

   $ rpm -Fvh  http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/$(uname -p)/os/Packages/f/fedora-release-20-1.noarch.rpm

   For the RPMFusion repos you can do the same thing:

   ```
   $ sudo rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-* | sort -u
   rpmfusion-free-release-19-1.noarch
   rpmfusion-nonfree-release-19-1.noarch
   ```

   So you're looking for `.rpm`  files named `rpmfusion-free-release-20*.noarch` & `rpmfusion-nonfree-release-20*.noarch`. Here are those files from the RPM Fusion website:

   ```
   $ sudo rpm -Fvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-20.noarch.rpm
   $ sudo rpm -Fvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-20.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Re-adding the fedora-release repo

   An alternative method would be to use the command `yum-config-manager` to re-add the `fedora-release` repository.

   ```
   $ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/testing/20/$(uname -p)/
   ```

   **NOTE:** This command will install the appropriate *32-bit* or *64-bit* repository based on your system's architecture using `uname -p`.
3. Re-installing?

   Another method for getting things repaired is to use the `yum` command `reinstall`.

   ```
   $ sudo yum reinstall fedora-release
   ```

   **NOTE:** This method will likely repair other repositories such as the `fedora-updates` repos, but requires at least a partially working install of the `fedora` repo, so it's a bit of a "catch 22". I would suggest running this command *after* you've the items in step #1 & #2 above.

#### References

- [HowTo: Permenantely disable repositories in CentOS / SL](http://linux-bsd-sharing.blogspot.com/2012/04/howto-permenantely-disable-repositories.html)
- [Restore original configuration files from RPM packages](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2012/03/26/restore-original-configuration-files-from-rpm-packages/)

Comment: Thank you. Turned out those repositories were disabled. I enabled them and they're showing up as green, but the problem still persists. Before and now, when I do `sudo yum search gtk+`, I'm shown matches for gtk `gtk2.x86_64 : The GIMP ToolKit (GTK+), a library for creating GUIs for X`. But when I try `sudo yum install gtk2.x86_64`, I get a message `Loaded plugins: langpacks
 Nothing to do`. I had seen the `--add-repo` command on a website while searching for how to install Chrome.

Comment: @Nav - try `yum clean all`, then the `yum install ...` cmd.

Comment: Nope. For this command,`sudo yum install gtk2.x86_64` I'm still getting this message `Loaded plugins: langpacks
Nothing to do`
. Also, the following files in `yum.repos.d` are showing up as files of zero size: `fedora.repo`, `fedora-updates.repo` and `fedora-updates-testing.repo`

Comment: @Nav - oh that's no good. If they're zero then you'll need to re-install the RPMs that provided them.

Comment: ok so I navigated to here `http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/f/` but still can't find out how to get the necessary rpm's. Google searches aren't helping either. A little help please?

Comment: @Nav - see updates.

Comment: Thank you very much. The commands for release worked, but it turns out what I really needed were the updates repositories. I went to yum.repos.d folder and deleted the zero size files and using your links, googled and found a solution. Turns out this is what I needed to to `sudo yum reinstall fedora-release`. Got the solution from here: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/35074/restore-fedora-official-repository-files/

Answer (score 1):

Could be other thing, but from your list of files in your repo directory, I can see the three fedora repos without any content.

Could you check this? I think that you deleted the content doing something.

> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root **0** Feb 2 09:34 fedora.repo

I just checked mine on fedora 19 and the screen is like this...

> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root **1180** dic 18 13:22 fedora.repo

After that you can do an update and install the packets.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the relevant `/etc/yum.repos.d/` files for Fedora 20, as root:

```
cd /root
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora/releases/20/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/f/fedora-release-20-1.noarch.rpm
rpm -i --force fedora-release-20-1.noarch.rpm
```

If that doesn't fix your issue, please, as a comment, show us the output of:

```
rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo
rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo
rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates-testing.repo
```

Comment: Thanks. To the first rpm command it shows `package fedora-release-20-1.noarch is already installed`. To the second it shows `fedora-release-20-1.noarch`. Third,`fedora-release-20-1.noarch` and fourth `fedora-release-20-1.noarch`

Comment: try `rpm -i --force fedora-release-20-1.noarch.rpm`